# update only targeted element with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, dom

I'm trying to update my cart page with ajax when someone increases or decreases the quantity of the products, my view logic is fine. My issue as I can infer is targeting the class "ajax_updater", as soon as I hit the quantity buttons ajax works, but instead on just the specific product, it targets all the products' quantity with the same class ".quantity-style" and changes the value as per the targeted product, so, if the quantity for product A is 4 after ClickEvent, the quantity for product B, D, F gets targeted and changed to 4 too, what could be a solution?

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="quantity">
        <p id="quantity-style" class="quantity-style">{{item.quantity}}</p>
        <div class="quantity-arrows">
            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" class="ajax_updater" data-action="add" src="{% static 'shop/images/arrow-up.png' %}">

            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" class="ajax_updater" data-action="remove" src="{% static 'shop/images/arrow-down.png' %}">
        </div>          
    </div>
{% endfor %}


function update_arrow() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var spinner = '<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:15px;" alt="loading" ></i>';

    $(".quantity-style").html(spinner).load(update_quantity_url);
    console.log(update_arrow_url);
}

$('.ajax_updater').click(function () {
    update_arrow();
    console.log('hit hit');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify which element to update, an easy way to do this is to pass the element to update in the function.

```
function update_arrow(container) {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var spinner = '<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:15px;" alt="loading" ></i>';

    container.find(".quantity-style").html(spinner).load(update_quantity_url);
    console.log(update_arrow_url);
}

$('.ajax_updater').click(function () {
    update_arrow($(this).closest('.quantity'));
    console.log('hit hit');
});
```

Comment: with your method, it targets the selected product but when I try to change the quantity of a different product after the click event without reloading, the data is matched with the initial targeted product and not the right one, any idea what's happening?